# Save pictureBox image to openFileDialog filename

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox, openfiledialog

I'm trying to save an image to a path that already is known: An `openFileDialog`'s fileName

However, I keep getting the same errors:

"A generic error occurred in GDI+." 
or 
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: filename

I've tried stuff like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(openFiles.FileName); // gives me "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
```

as well as

```
 pictureBox1.Image.Save(pictureBox1.ImageLocation); // gives me "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: filename"
```

Basically, all I would like to do is save the image to the path that's been established already.  Like opening an image in MSPaint, drawing on it, and saving it - no dialog comes up, it just saves to the path from the openFileDialog.

I cannot, *for the life of me,* figure out how to do this!

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You have to call Dispose() on the bitmap you originally loaded.  That releases the lock that Image.FromFile() puts on the file.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the Generic GDI+ error. :S

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to provide file name manually and store it in some field:

```
string _imagePath = @"C:\image.jpg";

void Save()
{
   pictureBox1.Image.Save(_imagePath);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work: string _imagePath = pictureBox1.ImageLocation;
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(_imagePath);

Comment: Why do you choose ImageLocation property? Has it been initialized with any value? If not, don't be suprised with ArgumentNullExceptions being thrown.

Comment: I've tried a ton of different things so far.  I figured the ImageLocation would give me what I want.  I want to save the current pictureBox's image to the path last opened by the openFileDialog.

Comment: Assign the opendialog's FileName property to the field _imagePath during loading image.

Comment: Close the MemoryStream used to read the image to avoid GDI+ error.

Comment: We won't be able to help you (provided that Sam's answer hasn't solved your problem) unless you publish a bit more code.